# Bash Script: syntax error near unexpected token `else'

Tags: bash, syntax-error

I'm trying to create simple script to check whether my external ip address has changed. However, I keep getting the following error:

> syntax error near unexpected token `else'

This is my code:

```
#!/bin/bash
DESTDIR=exip.txt
PREVIP=$(<$DESTDIR)
EXIP=$(dig +short myip.opendns.com @resolver1.opendns.com)
echo "External ip checker schript V1.0"
echo
echo
echo "Previous ip: $PREVIP"
echo
echo "Your current  external ip is $EXIP"
if [ "$PREVIP" == "$EXIP"]:then
 echo "Both IP-adresses are the same"
else
 echo "The IP addresses are diffrent"
 echo "Sending autoremote message.."
 curl "http://autoremotejoaomgcd.appspot.com/sendmessage?key=APA91bEAg6VebS03KS$
 echo "$EXIP" > "$DESTDIR"
fi
```

I've looked ad other topics about this error but i just can't figure it out.

Comment: use semicolon before `then`

Comment: And add a closing quote at the end of the URL you pass to `curl`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error is here:

```
if [ "$PREVIP" == "$EXIP"]:then
                         ^^
```

you need to add spaces around `[` and `]` and finally use semicolon:

```
if [ "$PREVIP" == "$EXIP" ]; then
                         ^^^
```

More generally, you can always use a tool called Shellcheck to check if your script has these common errors. It is both a command and a website, so you can paste your script in http://www.shellcheck.net/.

Comment: Thank you for your help. It works now.
Also thanks for the link.